# Czech and Request/Response problems in asp.net

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm working in a website, that run on C#, which is multilanguage and one of its language is Czech.

My problem is: when a send a form (contact form) the text that I filled in the text field gets messy. I mean, I type "Přeložit jakékoliv internetové stránky" and, in my database, I get "Prelozit jakékoliv internetové stránky".

I have to change de encoding depending on the language I'm viewing the website. I do it this way:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("cs-CZ");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
Request.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
```

It work for the generated HTML, but for the forms it does not.

Can any of you help me please?

[]s

Comment: Might be useful to see how the text is being captured + sent / saved; but what database are you using? what is the type of the field in the database? If MSSQL and `varchar` then change it to `nvarchar`.

Comment: It's MSSQL 2008 and the field type is nvarchar

Comment: One important observation: in my local machine, while developing, it works OK. But in the server, where the site runs, it does not.

Comment: So the háčeks get lost? Is that the only problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set globalization tag in web.config.
See, too, if form pass the correct encoding type.

Hope it works. =)